# Django prevent caching of included html fragment

Tags: django, templates, caching

I have a Django view which uses the decorator to enable caching:

```
@cache_page(24 * 60 * 60) # cache for 24 hours
def index(request):
    # view code
```

this view corresponds to a template like so:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% load i18n %}

{% block content %}
    html code
{% endblock %}
```

the base.html:

```
{% load i18n %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
      <div id="content">
      {% block content %}
      {% endblock %}
      </div>

      <!-- need to tun off caching here... -->
      <div id="sidebar">
          {% include "language_switcher.html" %}
          {% include "login_box.html" %}
      </div>
      <!-- ...and then back on -->

</body>
</html>
```

In the side bar I have a couple of dynamic elements which should not be cached. How can I 'turn off' the caching for this part of the template (sidebar) only?

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Check this app: https://github.com/codysoyland/django-phased and this blog post: http://www.holovaty.com/writing/django-two-phased-rendering/

Comment: Right on. This looks very promising.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you're aware of [template fragment caching](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/#template-fragment-caching) - I don't believe setting a lower value here will override a view-level cache set to a longer period, though.  This of course would mean you'd have to cache different parts of your index.html separately, which is feasible but not likely what you want.

You might also look at the `clearcache` tag for template fragments implemented [here](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1801/).

Comment: yes. I thought I could use the template caching if necessary, it was just convenient to cache the whole view. Template fragment caching may be the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can't, really. When you cache the whole view, Django doesn't process it at all. It just returns the same response from the cache, which includes the fully formed HTML. You *can* add vary headers to the cache, but that won't help you unless there's something to vary on (logged in user, etc.). It won't help with just a basic block of changing content not tied to anything else.

Remove the view-level caching and manually cache things *in* the view that you want. Otherwise, you're out of luck.